# How To Fix So Chars "on" And "search=+" Not Appear On Url After Submitting GET Method Form?

Tags: php, get

Why Chars "On" And "search=+" Appears On My Url After Submitting GET Method Form ?

This my form:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div align='center'>
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?col=<?php echo "$col&search=$search&limit=$limit&page=1";?>">
<label for="search">Search</label>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" required>
<br>
<label for="col">Search Type</label>
<input type="radio" name="col" id="keywords" required>Keywords
<input type="radio" name="col" id="keyphrase" required>Keyphrase
<br>
<label for="limit">Limit</label>
<select name="limit" id="limit">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="500">500</option>
<option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="search_links" id="search_links" value=" ">Search Links</button>
<br>
<button type="reset">Reset</button><br>
<br>
<br>
</form>
```

After submission I need form to send user to:
http://localhost/test/pagination_2.php?search=$search&col=$col=limit=$limit&page=1

eg:
http://localhost/test/pagination_2.php?search=heman&col=keywords&limit=2&page=1

```
search= keywords go here
col= the mysql tbl column to query
limit= search result per page
```

Problem is, I get sent to:
http://localhost/test/pagination_2.php?search=heman&col=on&limit=&search_links=+

Note the "col=on". There is no mysql tbl column called "on", hence getting error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'on = ?' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pagination_2.php:90 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pagination_2.php(90): mysqli_stmt_prepare(Object(mysqli_stmt), 'SELECT COUNT(su...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pagination_2.php on line 90

Q1. Why browser shows "col=on" and not "col=$col" (in this case "col=keywords") ?

Q2. Also, why in url gets added: "search=+" ? How to rid it ?
My code:

```
<?php

if(ISSET($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_type = 'member';
}
elseif(ISSET($_COOKIE['guest']))
{
    $user_id = $_COOKIE['guest'];
    $user_type = 'guest';
}
else
{
    die("Error 1: Invalid User!");
}

if(ISSET($_GET['search']) && is_string($_GET['search']))
{
    $search = $_GET['search'];
}
else
{
    die("Type your single Keyword or single Keyphrase!");
}

if(ISSET($_GET['col']) && is_string($_GET['col']))//'col=search_type'. 'search_type' options: 1). Mysql Column:keywords; 2. Mysql Column:keyphrase.
{
    $col = $_GET['col'];
}
else
{
    echo "Select Checkbox!";
    die("Select your search type to indicate whether you are searching for a single Keyword or a single Keyphrase!");
}
```

On the form, I selected "keywords" as the "col" to be queried:

```
<input type="radio" name="col" id="keywords" required>Keywords
<input type="radio" name="col" id="keyphrase" required>Keyphrase
```

Q3. How to fix this following line to solve the issue ?

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?col=<?php echo "$col&search=$search&limit=$limit&page=1";?>">
```

Q4. Need to add security in the url so no hacker can injection in url. Do I need to add urlencode in the above-mentioned code ?

Comment: You could perhaps add a value to your radio button. But it does illustrate that you need to check the data coming from your form, especially as it's using GET and is that much easier for anyone to call directly, prior to sending it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form as GET REQUEST, Some of the special characters cause problem,
e.g. if u have #(hash) in you text , then the text after #(hash) would be ignored from the uri when reading it on your server script.

So to Avoid this problem either you should submit your form as POST or use javascript to encode your url query parameters value by using encodeURIComponent().

Example to use **encodeURIComponent()**:

```
<script>
  var uri = "https://example.com/test.php?name=ståle&car=saab";
  var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
</script>
```

You must encode all of the form values before submitting it to the server side as GET REQUEST.

Comment: This is part of pagination code where you keyword search in the database. Hence, need to use $_GET method to have params in the url.
I do not have hash in my url.
I marked your answer. Mark not showing-up, though but vote got counted.

Comment: You need to include javascript into this, before submit it escape all value value then submit. And hash was a example which can also cause problem